# how to interpret the smoothed effect of time in GAMM models

Tags: r, misspecification, gamm4

I have recently taken a plunge into the world of Generalized Additive Mixed Models (GAMMs) after learning that including the quadratic and cubic fixed and random effects of time to understand students' reading growth trajectories made it impossible for my models to converge. To be specific, I switched to GAMMs because after rescaling and re-centering my predictor (time) variable, as suggested by R error and warning messages, I was still not successful and the lack of convergence perhaps suggested that imposing a strict functional form on students’ reading growth over time may be unrealistic which could have led to severe model misspecification.

I've read a lot of journal articles that introduce GAMM since, followed the tutorials in R to enhance my understanding.  After that, I attempted to apply it to my longitudinal data and I'm stuck with two seemingly basic question.  Here’s a brief overview of my research questions, how I specified them in R, and the results I obtained:

Overview:
I wanted to examine students’ reading growth trajectories across 3 academic years.  Each student has 3 data points within each year, so a total of 9 data points for all students.  Time, in this context, is the amount of of instruction time students received across 3 years.  I first ran an unconditional means model (step 1), and then an unconditional growth model (step 2).  After which, I wanted to enter substantive predictor variables that explain variability in students’ intercepts and slopes in reading over time.  But… I’m still stuck at step #2.

I first specified the unconditional growth model using GAMM function (instead of the traditional lme or lmer for purposes of comparing gamm objects later) where no smoothing effects was applied to the predictor of time, i.e., cumulative_months of_instruction_c (c stands for grand mean centered) like this:

`reading.uncond.growth.linear.gamm <- gamm(test_rit_score ~ cumulative_months_of_instruction_c, data=q2.reading.comp, random=list(student_id=~1 + cumulative_months_of_instruction_c))
summary(reading.uncond.growth.linear.gamm[[1]])
summary(reading.uncond.growth.linear.gamm[[2]])`

I obtained the following results for component [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgUhG.png)] of the model.

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
 Data: strip.offset(mf) 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  21379.82 21415.65 -10683.91

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 + cumulative_months_of_instruction_c | student_id
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
                                   StdDev     Corr  
(Intercept)                        17.2979996 (Intr)
cumulative_months_of_instruction_c  0.4383409 -0.316
Residual                            7.2842869       

Fixed effects: y ~ X - 1 
                                        Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
X(Intercept)                        189.92320 0.9737721 2575 195.03866       0
Xcumulative_months_of_instruction_c   1.04457 0.0292323 2575  35.73343       0
 Correlation: 
                                    X(Int)
Xcumulative_months_of_instruction_c -0.261

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-5.31250588 -0.50972456  0.01155442  0.51819776  4.93591979 

Number of Observations: 2898
Number of Groups: 322
```

Interpretation of the fixed effects of time: each additional month of instruction is associated with an increase of 1.04 units of reading score.  Sounds good.  Next, I applied a cubic smoothing spline to my time variable because my exploratory analyses suggest that the relationship between months of instruction and reading achievement is nonlinear. So I specified the syntax as:

```
reading.uncond.growth.gamm.smooth.cr <- gamm(test_rit_score ~ s(cumulative_months_of_instruction_c, bs="cr"), data=q2.reading.comp, random=list(student_id=~1 + cumulative_months_of_instruction_c))
```

Comparing the model fit of the two shows that the one with smoothing spline outperforms the model without. However, I am stumped by the fixed effects of the smoothed predictor, which increases dramatically from 1.04 to 30.53. Here's the complete output which contain the fixed and random effects using the following command:

```
summary(reading.uncond.growth.gamm.smooth.cr[[1]])
```

Here is what I obtained:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
 Data: strip.offset(mf) 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  21115.89 21157.69 -10550.95

Random effects:
 Formula: ~Xr - 1 | g
 Structure: pdIdnot
             Xr1      Xr2      Xr3      Xr4      Xr5      Xr6      Xr7      Xr8
StdDev: 2.943736 2.943736 2.943736 2.943736 2.943736 2.943736 2.943736 2.943736

 Formula: ~1 + cumulative_months_of_instruction_c | student_id %in% g
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
                                   StdDev     Corr  
(Intercept)                        17.2845761 (Intr)
cumulative_months_of_instruction_c  0.4471031 -0.314
Residual                            6.8098668       

Fixed effects: y ~ X - 1 
                                              Value Std.Error   DF   t-value p-value
X(Intercept)                              189.92224 0.9718436 2575 195.42470       0
Xs(cumulative_months_of_instruction_c)Fx1  30.53209 0.8880753 2575  34.38007       0
 Correlation: 
                                          X(Int)
Xs(cumulative_months_of_instruction_c)Fx1 -0.254

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-5.5113105 -0.5180834  0.0294039  0.5247907  5.5328421 

Number of Observations: 2898
Number of Groups: 
                g student_id %in% g 
                1               322
```

Question: How did simply adding a smoothing spline drastically increase the fixed effects of time by so much, again from 1.04 to 30.53?  Is it correct to then interpret that an additional month of instruction is now associated with 30.5 points increase in reading?  This result doesn't seem plausible and the "Fx1" attached at the end of my predictor in the output suggests that the variable is rescaled in some way.  If my interpretation of this fixed effect is incorrect, what is the right way of interpreting it? Or if it doesn’t make sense to interpret the smoothed fixed effect of time at all from this model, should I retain the value of 1.04 as the fixed effect of time when attempting to quantify the main effect of  time of instruction and reading performance and only interpret the significance of the smooth term, i.e., the non-parametric component of GAMM?

I've consulted multiple resources and they often compare the two models in terms of AIC, BIC, adjusted R squared, and the significance of smooth terms, but no one compared and interpreted the change in the fixed effects before and after adding the smoothing effects.  I’ve posted [the same question on SEMNET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgUhG.png) but I was not able to obtain an answer answer.

My second question is:  what does the following plot tell me?

```
plot(reading.uncond.growth.gamm.smooth.cr$gam, residuals=T)
```

[image: plot of partial residuals]

This plot appears to be a plot of partial residuals and seems to demonstrate the nonlinear effects of time on reading performance across years.  But what exactly is being partialed out?  And why is the x axis is time and y axis is the smoothing function of time with 8.66 in it?  Could someone explain in simple terms what this plot is trying to diagnose regarding what's displayed on the x and y axis?

Thank you so much for your time, and I look forward to learning more about GAMMs.

Comment: I suggest, you do `gam` instead of `gamm`. Read this paper regarding how to specify random effects with `gam`: https://peerj.com/articles/6876/

Comment: The plot shows one of the functions in the additive model, in this case a smoother function, i.e., `s(cumulative_months_of_instruction_c, bs="cr")`. The 8.66 is the estimated degrees of freedom of the smoother. Predictions would be derived by adding values from this function to values of all other function (there are none in your model) and the intercept. The plot does not depict residuals.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Do you know if there's another way to model the data, as described in the graph I posted?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I've looked at the paper you recommended, and I'm still concerned that I may run into the same problem interpreting the fixed results, i.e., fixed effect of1.04 without GAMM and 30.5 with GAMM, as described in the original post. Therefore, I'm now asking whether there could be another methodology that I can use to capture this association between instruction time and reading performance (the association looks just like the graph in this post) more succinctly with easy to interpret fixed and random effects. I'm a beginner  and am exploring options. Many thanks!